# How to implement a python class function that uses class and current object (self)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know we can explicitly write the name of the class to get class attributes, and when you need the method to get class attributes that change from object to object, then the 'self' as the first parameter, should work fine.

However, I don't really know how to do both in a fancy way.

```
class Alpha:
    base = 0
    round = 360

    def __init__(self, radius: float, angel: float = 0):
        self.radius = radius
        self.angel = angel

    def spin(self, angel: float = 0, K: int = 0):
        # need to use both 'base' & 'self.radius'
        #  should I use it like that?
        if self.radius is not Alpha.base and angel is not None:
            self.angel = (angel + (360 * K))
```

It's ok to use it as I did?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Does what you've done not work?

Comment: You can use `self.base`.  The class instance inherits values from the class.

Comment: Read about 'instance attributes' and 'class attributes' at https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/. And when you wrote "to get class attributes that change from object to object" you're actually referring to "instance attributes".

Comment: "How to implement a python class function that uses class and current object (self)?"—If a method references the current object it's not a class method. Class methods, by definition, don't have a "current object".

Comment: `self.base` and `self.round` will work for instances as well - but if you assign something to either of those then they will be different for that instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is fine if you're not going to subclass it

However if you are going to subclass it then use the following:

```py
class Alpha:
    base = 0
    round = 360

    def __init__(self, radius: float, angel: float = 0):
        self.radius = radius
        self.angel = angel

    def spin(self, angel: float = 0, K: int = 0):
        # need to use both 'base' & 'self.radius'
        #  should I use it like that?
        if self.radius is not self.__class__.base and angel is not None:
            self.angel = (angel + (360 * K))
```

`self.__class__` returns the class and not the object, however

```py
class Alpha:
    base = 0
    round = 360

    def __init__(self, radius: float, angel: float = 0):
        self.radius = radius
        self.angel = angel

    def spin(self, angel: float = 0, K: int = 0):
        # need to use both 'base' & 'self.radius'
        #  should I use it like that?
        if self.radius is not self.base and angel is not None:
            self.angel = (angel + (360 * K))
```

Would also work because the class variables are carried into the object, this would not work as intended with functions that do not have self as first

```py
class foo:
    def bar(foobar):
        return foobar * 2
foobar = foo()
foobar.bar("foo")
```

This would result in

`TypeError: bar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` or similar error

To prevent this error just do add the decorator staticmethod like the example given below:

```py
class foo:
    @staticmethod
    def bar(foobar):
        return foobar * 2
foobar = foo()
foobar.bar("foo")
```

`>>> foofoo`

Answer (score 1):

> It's ok to use it as I did?

I think this is the right way to create static class variables. I couldn't find any official resource, but lots of famous tutorial websites (like [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/) or [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/class-or-static-variables-in-python)) explain this technique.

---

Update: Here it is the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).